# Problem from Algebraic representation of complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers, complex-geometry

Prove that

$$√(7/2)≤|1+z|+|1-z+z²|≤3√(7/6)$$

For all complex numbers with $|z|=1$.

I proved $|1+z|+|1-z+z²|≤3$ so the right hand inequality

But didn't proved left hand inequality

Comment: Effort? MathJax?

Comment: Please see the question, I edited it

Comment: Try with $z=\cos t+i\sin t$

Comment: I don’t know any shortcuts but the formal way to do it is write the middle expression as $f(a,b)$ ($z=a+bi$) and set its partial derivatives to be zero, then use the Hessian matrix to find its minimum. I don’t know if this inequality’s bound is that tight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:  with $z = e^{i\,2 \varphi}\,$:

- $\displaystyle |1+z| = 2 |\cos \varphi|\,$;
- using the above, $\require{cancel}\displaystyle \left|1-z+z^2\right|=\left|\frac{1+z^3}{1+z}\right|=\frac{\cancel{2} \left|\cos 3\varphi\right|}{\cancel{2} |\cos \varphi|}=\left|4 \cos^2 \varphi-3\right|\,$.

Let $\,t = |\cos \varphi|\,$, then the problem reduces to finding the range of $\,2 t + \left|4t^2-3\right|\,$ for $\,t \in [0,1]\,$.